# Slider Revolution "revshowslide();" is not working on load

Tags: jquery, slider, revolution-slider

I'm really stuck at this problem. With using jQuery 1.11.1 and Slider Revolution from Codecanyon I tried to set up the code for changing the slider to a specific slide.

I'm using this code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($) {
   function readyFn() {
      revapi1.bind("revolution.slide.onloaded",function () {
         revapi1.revpause(); // this working
         revapi1.revshowslide(5); // this make me crazy
         return false; // actually not that necessary
      });
   }
$(document).ready(readyFn); 
})(jQuery);
```

For any reason every cmd like "revkill();" or "revpause();" is working except "revshowslide();". That's really confusing, maybe someone of you have some idea how to solve this?

One thing could be that there is no possibility to use that function inside the Event "revolution.slide.onloaded"... same with "revnext();", but I'm not sure.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you add details of the error you are getting. That will help people answer your question.

Comment: That's the thing - I don't get any error, it's just not working without any advice.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember...

Comment: In my case the issue wasI had the slider type set to `Scene`. Setting back to `Slider` fixed it.